# why is the space (shown in image) is added below when using vertical-align? How to fix it?

Tags: css

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="datePosted">
    <h6 class="eyeIcon">23</h6> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.datePosted h6{
    font-size: 1em;
    /*background-image: url(../Images/view4.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;*/
    padding-right: 6px;
    float: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: right;
}
.eyeIcon {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.eyeIcon:before{
    font-family: "foundicons";
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.eyeIcon:before{
    content: "\f005";
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*position: relative;
    top: 3.5px;  works nicely with this*/
    padding-right: 3px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

I want to align the `eye icon` vertically centered to the text 23, but when using `vertical-align:middle`, it does something like the image shown above. How is this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) to `middle` means aligning the midpoint to baseline plus half of the x height. This is what seems to happen in the image. To align to the middle of half the height of digits, you need to set `vertical-align` to a specific value corresponding to that height. This value unavoidably depends on the font.